# Open an SQL connection just once - mysqli_query

Tags: php, sql

I used

```
mysqli_connect("infos in here");
```

at the top of my page, and tried to use

```
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO and other info here");
```

When I do that, I get this error:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in (...)
```

---

But if I instead use

```
$con = mysqli_connect("infos in here");,
$mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO and other info here");
```

The error goes away, and my script works.

My problem is that I need to use mysqli_query two different times in my page, and I don't want to open the connection again when it's already open.

How can I handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: Open the connection as you have done in your second snippet and pass in the `$con` variable whenever you need it. Watch for scope issues inside functions.

Comment: You can't run a query without a connection. Just use the same connection across all your queries

Comment: Mike, I thought that would execute $con again and create a second connection. Thanks for teaching this noob. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that I need to use mysqli_query two different times in
>   my page, and I don't want to open the connection again when it's
>   already open.

How is it a problem ? open once query as many times then close the connection, example:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Perform queries 
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");
//one more
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,Age) 
                   VALUES ('Glenn','Quagmire',33)");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to connect two times. An example here..

```
$con = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "db");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die(mysqli_connect_error());
}
//Query one
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, 'Query String');

//Query Two
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, 'Query String'); //Used same $con variable

//After finishing all queries
mysqli_close($con);
```

If you need to select multiple database then

```
$con = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password");

//for DB bd_name1
mysqli_select_db($con, 'bd_name1');
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, 'Query String');

//for DB bd_name2
mysqli_select_db($con, 'bd_name2');
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, 'Query String');
```

But not connect frequent time.